# Binary String Regex Control Position

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex such that it matches all binary strings of length zero or more. The requirement is that the odd position must be 1 and even position can be either 1 or 0.

I am not sure how to control positions with regex?

My idea is something like `([1]+[01]*)+`

Sample:

- 10101
- 11111

Comment: Can `1` come in an even position too?

Comment: Can you please add some sample binary strings for better understanding?

Comment: Yes it can come in even position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove that quantifier from inside. Also, since you want to match 0 length string, you need to use `*` quantifier on complete regex, instead of `+`.

Try using the following regex:

```
(1[01]?)*
```

This will match:

- *1* at first place
- Then *0* or *1* in the 2nd place.
- 0 or more repetition, will make every odd position filled with *1*, and even position can contain *0* or *1*.
- `[01]` is optional to match odd length string.

Comment: Just to confirm if it is round bracket (), then * or + means repetition but if it is square bracket [], then * or + means combination?

Comment: @Mat.S. This is to do with the character class. A character class can matches a single character out of all the character inside `[]`. So, `+` or `*`, is repetition only. Just that, it will match repetition of any character from `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

try using this :

```
String data = "10111";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(1[01]?)*");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            // Indicates match is found. Do further processing
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```